How can be create setup exe for net-snmp-5.9.4?
Tutorials given on net-snmp says about installing and configuring snmp using

Microsoft Visual C++ - Configure / nmake - Building
Microsoft Visual C++ - Workspace - Building

But by using these two steps, setup.exe is not getting created.
I want to create setup.exe which can be used to install net-snmp.
